# How do you resolve HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable on IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, 503-error, permissions, iis

I'm getting a 503 error when trying to access the localhost web site on my Windows 7 machine. When I look in the event log I'm getting a load of errors along the lies of:

```
Windows cannot copy file \\?\C:\Users\Default\{979ea7af-5041-4710-838e-f2a62d4ddad2}\symimv.cat to location \\?\C:\Users\TEMP.IIS APPPOOL.001\{979ea7af-5041-4710-838e-f2a62d4ddad2}\symimv.cat. This error may be caused by network problems or insufficient security rights. 

 DETAIL - Access is denied.
```

I have not touched the security permission on this DIR, has anyone any idea what might have caused this & how to resolve it? It seems to have started after doing a large number of windows updates last night.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the temp IIS profile that is used (normal for IIS) can't be created.  I bet you will have the same issue if you create a new user and try to use it.  In other words, the root issue is not related to IIS.  I don't know what symimv.cat is, but nothing turns up on a google search.  Is that something custom that you or your corporate team have installed?

In other words, it sounds like something amiss with your default user profile.

Comment: Any idea how I would track down what that is?

Comment: Try first to just create a new windows user on that server and see if you can log into the server as that user.  The best debugging tool to use is process monitor from www.sysinternals.com.  That will let you know what permissions it needs and why it's failing.  You may just need to tweak the permissions on your symimv.cat file to give it read permissions for the Users group, or something along those lines.

Comment: So i tried creating a brand new user and loggin in and I get "The user Profile Service failed the logon. User Profile cannot be loaded." Looks like I might have more troubles than just running IIS.

Comment: Sounds like good confirmation.  Check Event Viewer and try Process Monitor and see what you get from those two clues.  They should help.  The symimv.cat file is suspect.  That's possibly a custom component added by someone, but hopefully not a virus.

Comment: Try copying the C:\Users\Default profile folder from another machine over this one (copy to desktop, zip, move, unzip to desktop, copy over c:\Users) and see if that helps. Came across this today on a dev vm :-\

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this. It was caused by the permissions being incorrect on the C:\Users\Default folder and as such the system could not read any of the files in the profile when trying to make a copy. The symimv.cat file was just the first file in the profile and was not significant, when I deleted it the next one in the list started comming up. symimv.cat is part of Norton 360 by the way.

Does anyone know what the correct default permissions are for C:\Users and C:\Users\Default? I have largly given rights to everyone, which is perhaps not very secure.